# Concatenating in Excel using IF condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the `sheet 1` that contains a dataset from columns A to Z
[image]

And a second sheet `sheet 2` that has a dataset from column A to B only
[image]

The above sheets have their first column a `time` value assignment.

How can I create a `sheet 3` where the column B in `sheet 2` will be assigned to all the columns in `sheet 1` where if and only if it meets this criteria:
The search should start in `sheet 2` row by row and at each iteration, the value of column A in `sheet 2` or the `time` and then comparing it with the column A in `sheet 1` where if the `time` value in `sheet 1` is `30 minutes` earlier than the one picked in `sheet 2` then here the condition is true and hence the compliant row in `sheet 1` will be merged with its corresponding value in column B in `sheet 2`.

Should the condition is not true, then the iteration described above in `sheet` should jump to next row for further comparisons.

Comment: sounds like a vlookup, but it's not very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your best bet is to format the data in the sheets as a Table (so you can use column names in your formulas for clarity's sake) then use INDEX / MATCH method of lookups.

If I understand your question correctly, I would recommend creating one column that would return a 1 or 0 to determine if your desired match/condition existed for including the row data, then the remaining columns in Sheet 3 could use the INDEX / MATCH to pull the data from Sheet 1.

See here for a good primer on INDEX / MATCH:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/